# python filter groups with the last row in groups are negative

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, pandas-groupby

I'd like to slice my data frame, based on some group conditions, and get all the groups whose last record has a negative value.

```
A B C D
1 a a 1
1 a a 2
1 a a 3
2 a a 1
2 a a -1
3 a a -1
3 a a -2
3 a a -3
```

Suppose this is my data frame, group by column A.
I want to get all the groups with a negative last value in column D.
output:

```
A B C D
2 a a 1
2 a a -1
3 a a -1
3 a a -2
3 a a -3
```

Column B and C are not related to the filter. But I need all the rows in each group, not only the last rows.
How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by column A and [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) over its result to filter which groups you want to keep.

Full functional example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
"B": ["a"] *8,
"C": ["a"] *8,
"D": [1, 2, 3, 1, -1, -1, -2 , -3]
    })

df.groupby('A').filter(lambda df_group: df_group['D'].iloc[-1] < 0)
```

Output:

```py
   A  B  C  D
3  2  a  a  1
4  2  a  a -1
5  3  a  a -1
6  3  a  a -2
7  3  a  a -3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `last` method to `groupby.transform` to get the last items and use `lt` to get a boolean mask that returns True if the last group value is less than 0 and filter `df`:

```py
out = df[df.groupby('A')['D'].transform('last').lt(0)]
```

Output:

```py
   A  B  C  D
3  2  a  a  1
4  2  a  a -1
5  3  a  a -1
6  3  a  a -2
7  3  a  a -3
```

Comment: Hi many thanks! I am not sure what lt(0) means? What if I need to filter <=0, how to change this condition?

Comment: That means less than.

Comment: @Canvas what keramat said. `lt`=`<`, `gt`=`>`, `eq`=`==`, `ge`=`>=` etc.; these are operator wrappers

Comment: @enke Hi what if I need to use df.loc to slice the last columns in every group?

Comment: @Canvas Do you mean without groupby?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
string = """A B C D
1 a a 1
1 a a 2
1 a a 3
2 a a 1
2 a a -1
3 a a -1
3 a a -2
3 a a -3"""


import numpy as np
data = [x.split() for x in string.split('\n')]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data[1:]), columns = data[0])
df['D'] = df['D'].astype(int)

#solution
temp = df.groupby('A')['D'].last()
df[df['A'].isin(temp[temp<0].index)]
```

Output:

[image]